# What is the best way to learn programming design?

Tags: performance, automation

What is the best way to learn about programming design?  I see lots of tutorials for programming languages, but a lot of them focus on specific language syntax.  I want to really get into the aspects of design, using programs efficiently, etc. Where should I start?

Comment: I heartily recommend Code Complete : http://www.amazon.com/Code-Complete-Practical-Handbook-Construction/dp/0735619670

Answer (score 2):

Read a  [book on algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849967202).

Learn OOP and read a [book on Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612)

Realize that making code readable is often more important than making it as efficient as possible, and most optimization should be left up to your compiler.

Answer (score 0):

If by programming design you mean design patterns, there are two books which are "classic" books for Design Patterns: 
- Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture, written by Martin Fowler;
- Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software, written by  Erich Gamma, Richard Helm, Ralph Johnson and John Vlissides (they're refered as GANG OF FOUR, or GoF).

To show their theories in practice, they usually pick a language whose object-orientation support is good to show their examples.

Martin Fowler uses Java and the Gang Of Four use Smalltalk and C++ but if you have any previous programming experience (which I believe you do), you can understand most of it.

Best of luck